# twitter bootstrap 2.2.1 popover nav not staying on hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

is there a easy way to make it so that when you use the popover ability in twitter boostrap 2.2.1 that it stays activated upon the trigger of hover? The reason I ask is because I have a menu of links I would like to be able to click on, with out having to trigger by click as clicking on the element should do things as well.

An example is WordPress, the admin panel has a series of icons in the nav bar and when I hover over them I get the hover popover as seen here:

[image]

from the image you can see I hovered over a icon an got a drop down. I cannot do a click event because that would wreck the main functionality of the icon in he collapsed state.

The code I am using is:

```
jQuery('#adminmenu li.wp-not-current-submenu.wp-has-submenu, .folded #adminmenu li.wp-has-submenu').popover({       
    html: true,
    title: function() {
        var title = jQuery(this).find('a.menu-top').html();
        return title;
    },
    content: function() {
        var submenu = jQuery(this).find('.wp-submenu').html();
        return submenu;
    },
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'hover',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - use an older version of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you want the popover to be triggered on hover and stay visible while you hover on the popover itself, you can use the "container" option to have Bootstrap append the popover to the target element. That way the popover is part of the target element and you're not hovering out.

You would need to add HTML IDs to each icon and use:

```
container: "#the-icon-id"
```

That also means you'd have one "popover" call for each element rather than using a selector like you're doing here (I don't know if there's a "container" value that would work in a generic way).

See http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers.